# SharePoint Client Object Model - Javascript or .Net?

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, 2016, .net

We currently have a SharePoint 2010 environment and planning to migrate to SP 2016(Q2 2019).
For SP 2010 we have developed a component to developers that want to consume SharePoint infrastructure. This component simplifies SharePoint Web Service calls and controls access to it trough a database. This allows us to track who is making changes in SharePoint trough a system, among other benefits. We have already adapted this component in the SharePoint 2016 farm, so migration should be transparent to developers using the component.

With that sad, some developers want to start using JavaScript to perform upload/download in SharePoint, where the access would be controlled trough SharePoint itself (ad groups on the lists).

I don't believe there are a lot of constraints on the JavaScript approach(please let me know if there are). But thinking on the migration, would the JavaScript Object Model for SharePoint 2010 be compatible with the one for SP 2016?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't believe there are a lot of constraints on the JavaScript
>   approach(please let me know if there are)

With Microsoft going in direction to support more client side development, they are already adding methods/ways to do things to SharePoint which was not supported in previous versions...We also have options to use JSOM or REST API based on our requirement. There are still come constraints which cannot be done using client object models, like we cannot perform any farm/web app level changes..but mostly almost everything is possible on site collection using client object model.

> But thinking on the migration, would the JavaScript Object Model for
>   SharePoint 2010 be compatible with the one for SP 2016?

JavaScript Object Model on SP 2010 like ECMA script are still compatible and will run as it is in SP 2016. But you might have to spend some efforts on validation part. This might be due to reason the way data manipulation being handled by developer...but officially it is still compatible with SP 2016.